# Python vectorized operation involving data from a previous row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I have pretty good grasp of how to utilize pandas and numpy to vectorize operations on entire columns of data.  However, I've come across a situation that I just can't seem to vectorize.  When the calculation involves utilizing a value from a previous row to calculate the current row, I have to fall back to a for loop.

Is it possible to vectorize this kind of thing?  Here is a simple example of what I mean:

```
# Test set of 20 random integers
df = pd.DataFrame({'base': [15, 16, 2, 16, 14,
                            1, 18, 18, 4, 7,
                            4, 18, 19, 13, 16,
                            11, 1, 8, 1, 9]})


# Empty array to hold calculated values
calc_data = np.empty((20, 1))

period = 14

for idx, value in enumerate(df.base):

    # Seeding the first element of the calculated array
    if idx == 0:
        calc_data[idx] = 5

    else:
        calc_data[idx] = (calc_data[idx - 1] * (period - 1) + df.base.iloc[idx]) / period

# Adding the column to the dataframe
df['calculated'] = calc_data

print(df)
```

Output:

```
    base  calculated
0     15    5.000000
1     16    5.785714
2      2    5.515306
3     16    6.264213
4     14    6.816769
5      1    6.401286
6     18    7.229765
7     18    7.999068
8      4    7.713420
9      7    7.662461
10     4    7.400857
11    18    8.157939
12    19    8.932372
13    13    9.222916
14    16    9.706994
15    11    9.799351
16     1    9.170826
17     8    9.087196
18     1    8.509539
19     9    8.544572
```

Comment: I don't think you can vectorize it

Comment: I don't think this is possible. The whole idea of vectorization is to apply an operation on an entire series/dataframe at once. If the value of a row depends on the calculated value of the previous one, then it's not possible to do 2+ of these simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks Pedro, I was afraid that might be the case, and that is my understanding of vectorization as well.  I was hoping I was missing something obvious.

Comment: About your only chance is to use a `ufunc` with a `accumulate` method, something like `cumsum`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One vectorized way (treating 'vectorized' as meaning 'avoiding Python-level loops') would be to treat it as a [linear signal filter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.signal

def via_lfilter(arr):
    period = 14
    y0 = 5.0  # initial value

    # calc_data[idx] = (calc_data[idx - 1] * (period - 1) + df.base.iloc[idx]) / period
    b = [1.0/period]  # coefficients of 'original' terms
    a = [1.0, -(period-1)/period]  # coefficients of 'computed' terms

    zi = scipy.signal.lfiltic(b, a, [y0], x=arr[1::-1])

    y = np.zeros_like(arr)
    y[0] = y0
    result = scipy.signal.lfilter(b, a, arr[1:], axis=0, zi=zi)
    y[1:] = result[0]

    return y
```

but in the real world, I'd just use numba, which is designed precisely to give us the performance benefits of vectorization without the headaches:

```
import numba

@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def via_numba(arr):
    calc_data = np.zeros_like(arr)
    period = 14
    calc_data[0] = 5.0  # initial value
    for idx in range(1, len(arr)):
        calc_data[idx] = (calc_data[idx - 1] * (period - 1) + arr[idx]) / period
    return calc_data
```

These give me:

```
In [238]: df["vect"] = via_lfilter(df.base.values.astype(float))
     ...: df["via_numba"] = via_numba(df.base.values.astype(float))
     ...: 
     ...: 

In [239]: df
Out[239]: 
    base  calculated      vect  via_numba
0     15    5.000000  5.000000   5.000000
1     16    5.785714  5.785714   5.785714
2      2    5.515306  5.515306   5.515306
3     16    6.264213  6.264213   6.264213
4     14    6.816769  6.816769   6.816769
5      1    6.401286  6.401286   6.401286
6     18    7.229765  7.229765   7.229765
7     18    7.999068  7.999068   7.999068
8      4    7.713420  7.713420   7.713420
9      7    7.662461  7.662461   7.662461
10     4    7.400857  7.400857   7.400857
11    18    8.157939  8.157939   8.157939
12    19    8.932372  8.932372   8.932372
13    13    9.222916  9.222916   9.222916
14    16    9.706994  9.706994   9.706994
15    11    9.799351  9.799351   9.799351
16     1    9.170826  9.170826   9.170826
17     8    9.087196  9.087196   9.087196
18     1    8.509539  8.509539   8.509539
19     9    8.544572  8.544572   8.544572
```

and both behave reasonably at larger frames:

```
In [240]: df = pd.DataFrame({"base": np.random.uniform(1, 100, 10**6)})

In [241]: %timeit via_lfilter(df.base.values.astype(float))
11.4 ms ± 49.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [242]: %timeit via_numba(df.base.values.astype(float))
11 ms ± 342 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

## tldr:

The following is vectorized in the sense that all operations used are array operations at the pandas & numpy layer.

```
X = ((period-1)/period) ** np.arange(len(df)) / period
a = df.base.copy()
a.loc[0] = 5*period
df['calculated'] = a.expanding().apply(lambda x: np.sum(x * X[:len(x)][::-1]), raw=True)
```

## explanation:

a fast solution can be constructed by extracting the sequential nature of the recursion.

i.e. note that each element of the result follow a certain pattern:

```
0: 5
1: 5 (13/14) + 16 (1/14)
2: 5 (13 / 14)^2 + 16 (13 / 14^2) + 2 (1/14)
...
```

if the first element is multiplied by 14, then we can represent the above as

```
0: sum{(1/14)*[70]}
1: sum{(1/14)*[70(13/14), 16]}
2: sum{(1/14)*[70(13/14)^2, 16(13/14), 2]}
...
```

If we remove the elements from `df.base` we get the series which can be summed:

```
0: (1/14) * [1]
1: (1/14) * [(13/14), 1]
2: (1/14) * [(13/14)^2, (13/14), 1]
...
```

This sequence of series above can be gotten as reversed slices of the following:

```
X = ((period-1)/period) ** np.arange(len(df)) / period
```

Also note that the first value of `df.base` is not used in the construction of `calculated`. Instead it is replaced by `(5*period = 70)`

So, the nth result is the sum of expanded series of modified `df.base` times the appropriate slice of `X`

```
a = df.base.copy()
a.loc[0] = 5*period
df['calculated'] = a.expanding().apply(lambda x: np.sum(x * X[:len(x)][::-1]), raw=True)
# df outputs:
    base  calculated
0     15    5.000000
1     16    5.785714
2      2    5.515306
3     16    6.264213
4     14    6.816769
5      1    6.401286
6     18    7.229765
7     18    7.999068
8      4    7.713420
9      7    7.662461
10     4    7.400857
11    18    8.157939
12    19    8.932372
13    13    9.222916
14    16    9.706994
15    11    9.799351
16     1    9.170826
17     8    9.087196
18     1    8.509539
19     9    8.544572
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use the shift() method to access the shifted value n places,

this should make your tasks easier

```
df.value.shift(1) + df.value
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I have considered shift which would work nicely if the column of values in 'calculated' already existed.  However, in this case it is calculating each row of 'calculated' on the fly and then using the previous row's value in the next row's operation.  Unless I am missing something I don't see how shift would alleviate this problem.