# Vectorising Calculation for 2 Interdependent Columns in Python

Tags: python

I am in the process of moving from Excel to Python. I need to calculate multiple columns of mostly interdependent data columns. I can accomplish this in Python by using a for-loop, but it is incredibly inefficient and takes unreasonably long. From the reading I've done, it is clear I need to vectorise the calculation. As a simplified example, kindly see the below screenshot from Excel. The grey columns are the static data, and the 2 yellow columns are those with formulas that are simply dragged down.

The for-loop I've used:

```
for i in range(1,n):

    df.loc[i, 'Value_1'] = df.loc[i-1, 'Value_2'] + df.loc[i, 'Day_chg']

    df.loc[i, 'Value_2'] = df.loc[i-1, 'Value_1'] + 
                           df.loc[i-1, 'Value_2'] + df.loc[i-1, 'Value_1']
```

[image: Data with Result]

| Date | Ticker | Close | Day_Chg | Value_1 | Value_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019/12/02 | AA | 43.79 |  |  |  |
| 2019/12/03 | AA | 43.32 | -1.07% | -1.07% | -1.07% |
| 2019/12/04 | AA | 43.49 | 0.39% | -0.68% | -2.83% |
| 2019/12/05 | AA | 43.48 | -0.02% | -2.85% | -6.36% |
| 2019/12/06 | AA | 43.88 | 0.92% | -5.44% | -14.65% |
| 2019/12/09 | AA | 43.73 | -0.34% | -14.99% | -35.08% |
| 2019/12/02 | BB | 30.07 |  |  |  |
| 2019/12/03 | BB | 25.63 | -14.77% | -14.77% | -14.77% |
| 2019/12/04 | BB | 27.68 | 8.00% | -6.77% | -36.30% |
| 2019/12/05 | BB | 23.58 | -14.81% | -51.11% | -94.18% |
| 2019/12/06 | BB | 22.63 | -4.03% | -98.20% | -243.49% |
| 2019/12/09 | BB | 19.69 | -12.99% | -256.48% | -598.18% |

The formula in column "Value_1" adds the previous day value from column "Value_2" to the current day value from column "Day_Chg".

[image: Formula 1]

The formula in column "Value_2" adds the previous day values from both columns "Value_1" and  "Value_2" to the current day value from column "Value_1".

[image: Formula 2]

I highly value any advice. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** after discussion in the comments.

Unfortunately, due to the fact that your columns are inter-dependent and also depending to previous rows, it is not possible to vectorise the computation of the two columns. Hence, iterating the rows one by one, similarly to what you proposed in your question is the only way. Any alternative you could find without explicitly writing a loop, would still use a loop under the hood.

Since you do not use indices or other features of Pandas, you can try to use `numpy` arrays instead of dataframes to speed up things.
To make the code significantly faster, you could optimise the code using `Numba`, which translates Python code into machine code just-in-time.

An example is this [answer to a question similar to yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51597293/2246849). I would love to help you with this now, but at the moment I don't have access to a machine with `Numba`. I will edit my answer in the next days. Maybe, in the meantime someone will also answer in this regard.

**EDIT2** as promised, here is the solution with `Numba` compared with a solution using `numpy` and one using `pandas`:

```
import numpy as np 
import numba 

@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def numba_calculate(day_chg):
    def fixna(x):
        return 0 if np.isnan(x) else x
    
    # The result array will have Value_1 and Value_2 in columns 0 and 1, respectively.
    result = np.zeros((len(day_chg), 2))
    for i in range(1, len(day_chg)):
        result[i, 0] = fixna(result[i-1, 1]) + day_chg[i]
        result[i, 1] = fixna(result[i-1, 0]) + fixna(result[i-1, 1]) + result[i, 0]
    return result


# Exact same function as numba_calculate, but without the Numba decorator.
def numpy_calculate(day_chg):
    def fixna(x):
        return 0 if np.isnan(x) else x
    
    # The result array will have Value_1 and Value_2 in columns 0 and 1, respectively.
    result = np.zeros((len(day_chg), 2))
    for i in range(1, len(day_chg)):
        result[i, 0] = fixna(result[i-1, 1]) + day_chg[i]
        result[i, 1] = fixna(result[i-1, 0]) + fixna(result[i-1, 1]) + result[i, 0]
    return result


def pandas_calculate(df2):
    def fixna(x):
        return 0 if np.isnan(x) else x

    for prev, curr in zip(df2.index, df2.index[1:]):
        df2.loc[curr, 'Value_1'] = fixna(df2.loc[prev, 'Value_2']) + df2.loc[curr, 'Day_Chg']
        df2.loc[curr, 'Value_2'] = df2.loc[curr, 'Value_1'] + fixna(df2.loc[prev, 'Value_1']) + fixna(df2.loc[prev, 'Value_2'])
```

Here is the timing of the solutions:

```
# Prints: 2.47 µs ± 8.17 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit numba_calculate(df['Day_Chg'].to_numpy())

# Prints: 42.6 µs ± 132 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit numpy_calculate(df['Day_Chg'].to_numpy())

# Prints: 1.05 ms ± 3.26 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit pandas_calculate(df)
```

As you can see, the solution using `Numba` is around 20 times faster than `numpy` and 400 times faster than looping with `pandas`.

Then, to assign the result back to the dataframe, you can simply do:

```
df[['Value_1', 'Value_2']] = numba_calculate(df['Day_Chg'].to_numpy())
print(df)
```

```
          Date Ticker  Close  Day_Chg  Value_1  Value_2
0   2019/12/02     AA  43.79      NaN   0.0000   0.0000
1   2019/12/03     AA  43.32  -0.0107  -0.0107  -0.0107
2   2019/12/04     AA  43.49   0.0039  -0.0068  -0.0282
3   2019/12/05     AA  43.48  -0.0002  -0.0284  -0.0634
4   2019/12/06     AA  43.88   0.0092  -0.0542  -0.1460
5   2019/12/09     AA  43.73  -0.0034  -0.1494  -0.3496
6   2019/12/02     BB  30.07      NaN      NaN      NaN
7   2019/12/03     BB  25.63  -0.1477  -0.1477  -0.1477
8   2019/12/04     BB  27.68   0.0800  -0.0677  -0.3631
9   2019/12/05     BB  23.58  -0.1481  -0.5112  -0.9420
10  2019/12/06     BB  22.63  -0.0403  -0.9823  -2.4355
11  2019/12/09     BB  19.69  -0.1299  -2.5654  -5.9832
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. The code you have provided makes perfect logical sense. How do you ensure that daily values for Value_1 and Value_2 are calculated row-wise? If I run the code you have provided, it calculates all the values for column Value_1 first, and then all the values for column Value_2. And needless to say I get results which differs from your results. To be clear, your results is the correct result. Many thanks.

Comment: @SarelLouw sorry, I did in fact misunderstand your question. Please see my edit.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback - I really appreciate it.

Comment: @SarelLouw as promised, I edited my answer with some options using `numpy` and `Numba` with runtime comparisons. As you can see, you can really speed it up even if it's not vectorisable.

Comment: Thank you very, very much. It is working like a charm. Is there another, perhaps more tangible way I can show my appreciation?

Comment: @SarelLouw No need to, all good, I'm here to help! But thanks