# Filter values within a percentage range based on the last non-filtered value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization, algebra

I have a Dataframe with the column "Trade" filled with some positive values; the rest are NaN values.

```
Trade
 100
 Nan
 Nan
 101
 Nan
 102
 Nan
 98
 107
 Nan
 101
 Nan
 98
 Nan
 Nan
 94
```

Among the non-Nan values, I need a vectorized solution to remove the values that fall within the 95%-105% value range of the last value that hasn't been removed. The final result should look like this:

```
Trade
 100
 Nan
 Nan
 Nan
 Nan
 Nan
 Nan
 Nan
 107
 Nan
 101
 Nan
 Nan
 Nan
 Nan
 94
```

Comment: What is "*the last value that hasn't been removed*"? Do you want an iterative solution?

Comment: If you compare the first and second values the second needs to have an absolute percentage difference higher than 5% to remain if it doesn't and it's removed then the first value will continue to be the last value that hasn't been removed and will be used as a reference for the third value otherwise if the second value meets the condition then this second value will be used instead. If the second, third, and fourth values are removed the fifth value will be compared to the first (the last value that hasn't been removed). Basically, once the condition is met the reference for the diff changes.

Comment: If your operation involves data from the previous row you can't really "vectorize" it since the idea of vectorizing is that you apply the same operation on each row at once without needing the previous value. You might want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51594900/python-vectorized-operation-involving-data-from-a-previous-row though.

Comment: It is possible to use auxiliary columns or arrays to do this and even recurrent vectorized operations. I'm not looking for 1 vectorized operation but a sequence.

Comment: It's indeed not possible to vectorize this, you have to iterate

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out since there is a dependency between the algorithm and the resultant rows there won't be a pure "single-pass" vectorized solution. However, you can still take a "shrinking" window approach to solve this problem while trying to minimize the number of iterative steps required.

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas import NA

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'trade': [100, NA, NA, 101, NA, 102, NA, 98, 107, NA, 101, NA, 98, NA, NA, 94]}
).astype({'trade': 'Int32'})

tmp = df.dropna()
valid = [0]
while valid[-1] < tmp.index[-1]:
    chunk = tmp.loc[valid[-1]:, 'trade'] # get window of all unprocessed data
    target = chunk.iat[0]
    valid.append(                        # find the first boundary
        chunk.between(target * .95, target * 1.05).idxmin() 
    )

print(
    f'{valid = }',  # [0, 8, 10, 15] (while loop took len(valid) iterations)
    df.assign(      # mask over values not in `valid`
        cleaned=lambda d: d['trade'].where(d.index.isin(valid)),
    ),
    sep='\n\n',
)
# valid = [0, 8, 10, 15]
#
#     trade  cleaned
# 0     100      100
# 1    <NA>     <NA>
# 2    <NA>     <NA>
# 3     101     <NA>
# 4    <NA>     <NA>
# 5     102     <NA>
# 6    <NA>     <NA>
# 7      98     <NA>
# 8     107      107
# 9    <NA>     <NA>
# 10    101      101
# 11   <NA>     <NA>
# 12     98     <NA>
# 13   <NA>     <NA>
# 14   <NA>     <NA>
# 15     94       94
```

The reason I refer to this as a "shrinking" window approach is because each tick of our while-loop will work on a smaller chunk of the DataFrame, until we have consumed all of it. This allows us to leverage as many DataFrame/Series methods as possible so we're not doing any data processing at the Python level.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

```
import pandas as pd

stop = 0.05

# Prepare

trade = df['Trade']
trade.fillna(0, inplace=True)
trade = trade[trade != 0]

# Filter

trade.loc[(trade > trade.shift(1) * (1-stop)) & 
 (trade < trade.shift(1) * (1+stop))] = 0


# Recompose Dataframe

df = df.merge(trade.rename('T1'), left_index=True, 
right_index=True, how='left')
df['Trade'] = df['T1']
df = df.drop(['T1'], axis=1)
```

In the end, the actual filtering took only 1 line of code and I'm sure the rest can be improved. I thought I would've had to loop the filter a couple of times but in the end, it wasn't needed. No lambda, no loops, and no ifs.